# "Bad request" when trying to delete a entry in a Lightswitch database

Tags: odata, restsharp

I'm trying to delete entries in my lightswitch database, from a external app.
I'm using restsharp, and the code looks like the following:

```
var request = new RestRequest("/FilesSet/{Id}", Method.DELETE);    
request.AddParameter("Id", 8);    
var resp = client.Execute(request);
```

Here is the full error message:

```
The request URI is not valid. Since the segment 'FilesSet' refers to a collection, this
must be the last segment in the request URI. All intermediate segments must refer to a
single resource.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems like you're trying to locate an entity and delete it. In the OData URL convention, the canonical URL for accessing an entity in a collection is as follows:

~/FilesSet({Id})

Thus, you need to modify your code as follows:

```
var request = new RestRequest("/FilesSet({Id})", Method.DELETE);    
request.AddParameter("Id", 8);    
var resp = client.Execute(request);
```

Reference: [4.3.1 Canonical URL](http://docs.oasis-open.org/odata/odata/v4.0/os/part2-url-conventions/odata-v4.0-os-part2-url-conventions.html#_Toc372793775)

Comment: This doesn't work either. It gives me the following error: "Bad Request: Only 'If-Match' headers are supported for Update/Delete operations."